# Network Triangulation in Android

Tags: android

I am developping an Android app, I need to get current location using Network Triangulation,
Does "LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER" support for the Network Triangulation or does it only provide the cell tower location?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer for my own question :). I'll post it for viewers reference.

Yes, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER support for Network Triangulation. Google has done everything. we don't need to worry about the calculation. It gives you fairly correct locations.